# ko.renderTemplate and requirejs loader

Tags: jquery, templates, knockout.js, requirejs, knockback.js

I want to use knockout's renderTemplate function in a requireJS project/module.

I want to load the templates via the !text or !tmpl plugin.

Currently I end up with: "Uncaught Error: Cannot find template with ID ..."

A normal call would look like this:

```
ko.renderTemplate('personTmpl', { name:"test1" });
```

**But** this will search the DOM for something like:

```
<script id="personTmpl" type="text/javascript"/>
```

And thereby create a dependency on existing dom-nodes

But since I am building a requirejs-module, which looks like this (simplified **& not working**):

```
define(["knockout",
    "tmpl!templates/persons.html",
    "text!templates/persons.html",
    ],function(ko, personTmpl, personTmpl2){
        ko.renderTemplate('personTmpl', { name:"test1" });
        ko.renderTemplate('personTmpl2', { name:"test1" });
    });
```

Requirejs does not include my persons.html content as script-tag!

I can't find a way to make **ko.renderTemplate** consume anything other than script-IDs.

How can I make this work?

One solution might be loading the templates via requirejs and then pipe them into a script tag, like this:

```
var script = document.createElement( 'script' );
script.type = 'text/javascript';
script.id = "url";
$("head").append( script );*/
```

**But I dont like this approach.**

How to make the following work?

```
define(["knockout",
    "tmpl!templates/persons.html",
    "text!templates/persons.html",
    ],function(ko, personTmpl, personTmpl2){
        ko.renderTemplate(personTmpl, { name:"test1" });
        ko.renderTemplate(personTmpl2, { name:"test1" });
    });
```

So the question may break down to:

How to make this work: (or anything thats equivalent)?

```
ko.renderTemplate('<div>huhu</div>', { name:"test1" });
```

or this:

```
ko.renderTemplate($('<div>huhu</div>'), { name:"test1" });
```

Comment: you might be interested in my library here: https://github.com/rniemeyer/knockout-amd-helpers.  It lets you do `data-bind="template: 'myTemplate'"` and loads it using the `text` plugin automatically and allows you to configure the path and extension of the files.

Comment: this sounds ***very promising!*** thx alot!
(i was stuck here for quite some time)